# Replacing button images shows weird issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, uibutton, uiimage

I have two images I used for showing on/off. Everything was working perfectly. When my designer asked to replace the images, I replaced the images and replaced the name of the images in the class. Suddenly the switching isn't happening any more. I used `[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];`  With condition. My condition is working perfectly. But image never changes. Replacing these images with the old images worked perfectly for the same code.

Now, I again replaced it back it to the new images and added setBackgroundColor for Button. Strangely the images are getting replaced. If I take away the backgroundColor method it doesn't work. Does anyone knows why this happens?? I think the image is getting set as background image as well. But I haven't used a single code anywhere to set the background image.

**Update**

This is the place I set the images. Where in viewDidLoad

```
selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kcheckSelected];
notSelectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:kcheckUnselect];

-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

    static NSString *identifier = @"cellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, tableview.frame.size.width - 15, 1)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:view];
    }


    NSString *sltd= [selectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UIImage *image    = nil;
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableview.frame.size.width - 60, 5, 60, 50)];
     if ([sltd isEqualToString:@"yes"])
    {
        image = selectedImage;
    }
    else
    {
        image = notSelectedImage;
    }
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(selectButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:button];

    User *userObj = [userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = userObj.name;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Montserrat-Regular" size:17];
    if ([userObj.installOnIpad boolValue] == YES)
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-icon-active"];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ipad-icon-disabled"];
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Are you sing Image Assets?

Comment: are you calling the method on main thread?

Comment: I am using image assets, but this particular image was outside.  Just added it in the project using drag and drop, but, with the copy to project option turned on.

Comment: @Harry Yes am calling it in the main thread.

Comment: @AbinGeorge Why don't get out the assign images inside your selectButton selector? In other words, you know initial value (and image) and you just change it when press button. If I wrong understood, maybe you call [tableView reloadData] in didLayout or WillAppear event.

Comment: @Beto thanks for the suggestion. Actually am having as you see a number of cells with this button. The configuration of the selection changes according to selecting a button. I mean, there are preferences for the cells. In one case, if I select a button, all other buttons should get deselected. So, we cant use setImage for the sender. Orelse I would have definitely done that. Thank you for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: @AbinGeorge check if your kcheckSelected image name does not have .png in its name, if you are using assets catalog or you must use .png (or whatever) if you don't use it

Comment: @Beto Nope, it didn't change anything.